# How to fix display position to desired value in CSS3 using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, position, icons

I am trying to achieve the icon shown below, using combination of 2 bootstrap icons:

[image]

I tried giving margin\top\right. None of it seem to have any effect.
This is what I have tried so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyahdt2x/1/)

Code:

```
  <div class="row pull-right" style="margin-right: 50px; margin-top: 10px;">
  <div id="toggleIcon">


        <div class="eye">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open adjust-eye"></span>
        </div>
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS: (in fiddle)

Kindly let me know how can that be achieved and also why isn't margin\top\right working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#toggleIcon .eye{position: relative; bottom:-20px;}
```